# javascript reduce returning undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

my reduce code is not working, my accumulator is accumulating as expected, but the output I get is undefined, could someone please point out my error?

```
function total(arr) {
  arr.reduce(function(acc,cur){
    console.log(acc);
    console.log(cur);
    return acc+cur;
    });
  }

let s=total([1,2,3]); 
console.log(s);
```

Comment: Your `total()` function does not have a `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

you are forget to return the function

```js
function total(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(acc,cur){
  //^^^^^ missing
  return acc+cur;
    });
  }

let s=total([1,2,3]); 
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return arr.reduce

```
function total(arr) {
  return arr.reduce...

  }

let s=total([1,2,3]); 
console.log(s);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate why was it in first place undefined, and how is that fixing it?

Comment: @TomerShetah This is from MDN:

The expression whose value is to be returned. If omitted, undefined is returned instead.

Here is the link:

[MDN - return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)